# Can we use NDEBUG on assembly files?

Tags: c, assembly, makefile

So basically I have a program written in C which consists of a couple of `.c` files. The makefile for them looks like this :

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEBUGFLAGS=-D NDEBUG -O3
default: all

all: fib.o bigint.o bigintadd.o
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -o fib fib.o bigint.o bigintadd.o

fib.o: fib.c bigint.h
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -c fib.c -o fib.o $(CFLAGS)

bigint.o: bigint.c bigint.h bigintprivate.h
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -c bigint.c -o bigint.o $(CFLAGS)

bigintadd.o: bigintadd.c bigint.h bigintprivate.h
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -c bigintadd.c -o bigintadd.o $(CFLAGS)
```

It all works fine, but I decided to rewrite `bigintadd.c` into assembly. However, when I launch the modified program, it takes twice more time to execute. I wonder if I can add `NDEBUG` for `.s` file in the makefile ? If not, then are there any options which can help me to improve the time of execution ? The makefile for the program with `bigintadd.s` instead of `bigintadd.c` :

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEBUGFLAGS=-D NDEBUG -O3
default: all

all: fib.o bigint.o bigintadd.o
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -o fib fib.o bigint.o bigintadd.o

fib.o: fib.c bigint.h
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -c fib.c -o fib.o $(CFLAGS)

bigint.o: bigint.c bigint.h bigintprivate.h
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -c bigint.c -o bigint.o $(CFLAGS)

bigintadd.o: bigintadd.s bigint.h bigintprivate.h
    as bigintadd.s -o bigintadd.o $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: That just means you have written worse code than the compiler ;) `NDEBUG` won't help (have you tried it?)

Comment: *"I wonder if I can add NDEBUG for .s file in the makefile"* - How is a C preprocessor macro supposed to affect assembly files? I'm sorry to say this, but the reason it's slower is because you aren't half as good at writing assembly as your compiler is. Most humans aren't.

Comment: So the only option I have to make the program run faster is to optimize my assembly code, right ?

Comment: @Artjom Yes, indeed.

Comment: If you haven't written your own code to make use of it, `NDEBUG` only affects `assert()` from `<assert.h>` (with `NDEBUG` active, it turns into a no-op and is compiled out).

Comment: NO. To make it faster you use a professional bigint library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I understood is that the C preprocessor macro `NDEBUG`does not affect assembly files. Hence, it is impossible to make it run faster by adding stuff in the makefile. The only way that might work out is to optimize the `bigintadd.s` code by myself. Thank you everyone who helped !

Comment: `NDEBUG` doesn't make C code run faster, either. It does not magically enable the optimizer. You have to specify that switch, something like `-O2` or `-O3`, which will automatically define `NDEBUG`. There is no such thing as optimization settings for your assembler. It assembles the code exactly as you write it. If that code is sub-optimal, the output will be sub-optimal, too. Very unlikely that you can do better than the compiler. If you have something that is in the ballpark and gives the correct results, ask a new question about optimizing it over on [CodeReview.SE]. Those are always fun.

Comment: @CodyGray "NDEBUG doesn't make C code run faster, either".. Maybe I misunderstood you, but C code without NDEBUG parameter takes 10 times more to execute (the purpose of the program is to find fibonacci numbers and I test it on fib(500000)

Comment: That is an accident. What you *should* be doing is enabling optimization. Read the rest of the comment.